# Disable buffering/caching for a file

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I am executing some benchmarking using a DBMS and virtual machines. And I am using this command

```
free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free
```

on each Guest, and on each Host, before executing a query, to minimize the effect of cache/buffering on my execution time. If the data is cached/buffered the execution time for a query may vary depending on what query was executed before, because a part of the file used to answer the query might be in memory.

I would like to automatize the process (I am doing this manually) but it's a little tricky to execute sync/drop caches after each query. I need to ask for every VM and for every physical server to sync/drop caches. I could write a script, and use SSH to do this, but I wonder if there's a way to keep the OS from buffering/caching the files.

I also found this tool:
https://github.com/Feh/nocache

But it requires me to execute it together with the program that can't use cache. What I have is a distributed DMBS running on a virtual machine enviroment, so it's no straightforward how to use it for my case. I use a command to inilizate each instance on each server, and they are on top of a VM.

P.S.:I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on all the VMs (using KVM) and servers.

Comment: On the **hosts** this is quite easy: Set KVM to use no caching on the disk files!

Comment: Thanks Eugen Rieck. Could you tell me how I can do this? Or at least point me to some material?

Comment: put `cache=none` into the domain XML, something like `<disk type='file' device='disk'><driver name='..' cache='none'> ...`